# Php Laravel Migrations

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-7

**What is wrong with this migration it is still giving me the error :**

```
public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('menus', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->boolean('visibility');
                $table->integer('priority');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->string('tag');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('created_by_user_id')->index();
                $table->foreign('created_by_user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            });
        }
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `menu`.`menus` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `menus` add constraint `menus_created_by_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`created_by_user_id`) reference
> s `users` (`id`))

Comment: Foreign keys need to be of the same type as the column they're referencing (`id` on your `users` table). Please post the migration for your `users` table

Comment: On user migration file, it also `$table->bigIncrements('id');`?

Comment: btw, no need to index a foreign key, it will be indexed auto

Comment: Thanks guys the problem is solved. The user table id column was id() now changed to BigIncrements.

Comment: `$table->id();` is alias of `$table->bigIncrements('id')`

Comment: @jewishmoses `$table->id();` is alias of `$table->increments('id');` in some older version of laravel.

Comment: @jewishmoses thanks for your comment, I'm using laravel 7, and I don't know what cause the problem when i use id() on column. when i used Big Increment it works perfectly.

Comment: You can also use `$table->foreignId('created_by_user_id')->constrained('users');` instead  of both